# pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py is empty file

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, compatibility

Installed tensorflow 2.4.0 under Python 3.8.5 on openSUSE Leap 15.2, using pip into a recently created virtual environment.
My code executes "import tensorflow as tf", which ultimately executes

```
try:
  from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
```

This fails with "illegal instruction".
I find two issues:

1. pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py is an empty file;
2. There is no file _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so.

I tried downgrading python to 3.6.x and reinstalling everything. This fails due to another compatibility issue. Any ideas where to look or what to try next?

---

Dump follows:

```
(karoo) (sage-sh) rllozes@S300Think:kstaats-karoo_gp-8e1af80$ python3 -X dev karoo_gp.py
Fatal Python error: Illegal instruction

Current thread 0x00007fcb4249f740 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1101 in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 556 in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 657 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "/home/rllozes/Research/SR/karoo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1042 in _handle_fromlist
  File "/home/rllozes/Research/SR/karoo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 39 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "/home/rllozes/Research/SR/karoo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 41 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "modules/karoo_gp_base_class.py", line 35 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "karoo_gp.py", line 52 in <module>
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
(karoo) (sage-sh) rllozes@S300Think:kstaats-karoo_gp-8e1af80$
```

Comment: If it matters, I should add that I do not have a CUDA-capable GPU. The processor is a XEON E5-1620, which does have AVX.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the [Intel Optimization for Tensorflow](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide.html) works on my machine. Just follow the instructions.

**N.B.** pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py remains empty, but no error ensues.